# Rendering LinearLayouts seems to be slow

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I have been experiencing some part of MainActivity layout is slow to be inflated. Any reason ? It looks last 2 nested linear layouts (from the bottom) are pushed up by the application while launching. Below is layouts and they are inside a RelativeLayout. Thanks in advance.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout73"
    android:weightSum="2"
    android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
    android:layout_above="@+id/linearLayout3"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true">
    <EditText
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="33dp"
        android:id="@+id/edittextID"
        android:textColor="@color/fonttextcolor"
        android:editable="false"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:textSize="@dimen/font_size_select"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/some_name"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded_edittext" />

    <Button
        android:text="@string/some_action"
        android:background="@drawable/button_shape_yellow"
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="33dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:id="@+id/buttonSomeAction"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:minLines="1"/>
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout3"
    android:weightSum="4"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true">
<Button
    android:text="@string/display_text"
    android:background="@drawable/button_shape_yellow"
    android:layout_width="60dp"
    android:layout_height="33dp"
    android:id="@+id/displaytextID"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:layout_weight="1"/>

<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageButton
    android:layout_width="60dp"
    android:layout_height="33dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:background="@drawable/button_shape_yellow"
    app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_xy1"
    android:id="@+id/buttonanother1"
    android:layout_weight="1"/>

<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageButton
    android:layout_width="60dp"
    android:layout_height="33dp"
    android:background="@drawable/button_shape_yellow"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:id="@+id/buttonanother2"
    app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_xy2"
    android:layout_weight="1"/>

<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageButton
    android:layout_width="60dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_height="33dp"
    android:background="@drawable/button_shape_yellow"
    app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_xy3"
    android:id="@+id/buttonanother3"
    android:layout_weight="1"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: its not linear layout problem.

Comment: can you put java code?

Comment: i don't think java code is the issue. here'e my mainactivity class implementation, public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

 setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}

Comment: can you put complete xml file content?

Comment: i don't think java code has any problem. here'e my mainactivity class implementation, public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

 setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}  i removed all code just to avoid side effect, still got the same behaviour.  i think, a linearlayout overloaded by too many image buttons could be an issue.

Comment: solved! had been using older android studio. recently i upgraded to 2.3.2. there's absolutely no issue.  here's gradle, if it helps others.

Comment: apply plugin: 'com.android.application' android {
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.0"
    compileSdkVersion 25
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.mycompany.yourcompany"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 0
        versionName "0.0.0"

    }

Comment: buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:6.5.87'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.0.0'
}